# I need a function to check string values in pandas df columns and cannot find an answer

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, function

I made a pandas df from parts of 2 others:
Here is the pseudocode for what I want to do.
4-column pandas dataframe, values in all columns are single words cols A B C D 
and I want this: cols A B C D E F 
in pseudcode (for every s in A; if s == any string (not substring) in D; write Yes to E (new column) else write No to E; if str in B (same row as s) == str in C (same row as string found in D) write yes to F (new column): else write No to F)
The following code works but now I need a function to do what is described above:

I'm not allowd to paste images of sample data and expected outcome.

```
cols = [1,2,3,5]
df3.drop(df3.columns[cols],axis=1, inplace=True)
df4.drop(df4.columns[1],axis=1, inplace=True)
listi = [df4]
listi.append(df3)
df5 = pd.concat(listi, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Can you please share example of data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

I created a sample data frame

```py
>>> df
       A          B        C          D
0  alpha  spiderman    theta   superman
1   beta     batman    alpha  spiderman
2  gamma   superman  epsilon       hulk
```

Now add `column E` that shows if item in `A` is in `C` and add `column F` that shows if item in `B` is in `D`

```py
>>> df['E'] = df.A.isin(df.C).replace({True: "Yes", False: "No"})
>>> df['F'] = df.B.isin(df.D).replace({True: "Yes", False: "No"})
>>> df
       A          B        C          D    E    F
0  alpha  spiderman    theta   superman  Yes  Yes
1   beta     batman    alpha  spiderman   No   No
2  gamma   superman  epsilon       hulk   No  Yes
```

Comment: Hi My description was lacking. I need one more column. That is is to capture the string in C in line 1 and put it in a new column. btw is line 2 not a repetition of line 1? Would isin() also match a substring of the target? The idea is that the strings should be identical.

Comment: Documentation says so `
Check whether values are contained in Series.

Return a boolean Series showing whether each element in the Series matches an element in the passed sequence of values exactly.`

Comment: Edited the typo. I copy pasted line 2 twice

Comment: Hi can you add in the extra column G with the string in C if B matches C. Then its perfect.